# Express a complex number in the Cartesian form

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $z$ the complex number $z=2^3\cdot i^{-47}/(1+i)^3$.
The question is: how to express $z$ in the Cartesian form $2-2i$?

I dont know how to express $z$ into $2-2i$. I just can't get this answer!!!!

Comment: Please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Hint: $\,i^{-47}=-i\,$ (*why?*). Your turn now.

Comment: Hint: $\dfrac{1}{1+i}=\dfrac{1-i}{2}$.